# Bug in jQuery UI color fading navigation menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a color fading menu similar to the one on www.guitaracademy.nl using jQuery UI. It almost works, but there is still a bug in it. Here is my example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#navbar ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
#navbar li {float:left;}
#navbar a {width:100px; display:block; color:#7e8fd2; background-color:#001155; text-align:center; padding:4px; text-decoration:none;}
#navbar a.selected {color:white !important;} /*important so as to override inline style generated by jQuery UI*/
div.panel {position:absolute;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var color_bg = "#001155";
var color_text = "#7e8fd2";
var color_bg_hover = "#384b97";
var color_text_hover = "#9aa7d8";
var color_bg_pressed = color_bg;
var color_text_pressed = "#ffffff";

$(function(){
    $("div.panel:not(:first)").hide();  // hide all panels except the home panel

    var loc=window.location;
    window.location.replace(loc+"#home");   // make window location correspond to home panel

    var menu=$("#navbar a");
    menu.click(function(){
        var previous=window.location.hash;
        var selected=$(this).attr("href");
        if (previous != selected) {
            $("div.panel"+previous).fadeOut();
            $("div.panel"+selected).fadeIn();
            }
        menu.removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    var hovermenu=menu.not(".selected");

    hovermenu.hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: color_bg_hover,
            color: color_text_hover
        },"fast");
    },function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: color_bg,
            color:color_text
        },"slow");
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="panel" id="home">This is my home page.</div>
<div class="panel" id="portfolio">This is my portfolio page.</div>
<div class="panel" id="contact">This is my contact page.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that all navigation buttons except the currently selected/active one "light up" when you hover over them.

The problem is as follows. In the initial state in which the "home" panel is displayed, the highlighting works as desired. However, if I then click on another button (say, "contact") and then hover over the "home" button again, it doesn't "light up". Also, if I hover over the "contact" button it lights up, whereas it's not supposed to since it is currently selected. In short, it seems like my selector

```
var hovermenu=menu.not(".selected");
```

is not "updating" upon navbar click events. Any ideas on how I could make it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover event doesnt seem to bind with the selected menu when initialized.
Hence, it doesnt seem to work with home.

Can try - Demo http://jsfiddle.net/pwvmk/5/

```
menu.hover(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: color_bg_hover,
            color: color_text_hover
        },"fast");

    }
},function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            backgroundColor: color_bg,
            color:color_text
        },"slow");
});
```

Comment: Hi Jayendra, that's it, thanks! I see now that the condition should indeed be put inside the hover(), so that it is evaluated on each hover event instead of just once when the page loads. (I was considering using delegate(), but this also works).